# Understanding Vulkan uniform layout's 'set' index

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I've been following along in the (very awesome) nvpro raytracing tutorial and have a question about the way the CameraProperties uniform buffer is bound using `layout(binding = 0, set = 1)` - I understand the binding = 0, but why set = 1?

The tutorial says "The `set = 1` comes from the fact that it is the second descriptor set passed to `pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setPSetLayouts`", but when I look at `HelloVulkan::createGraphicsPipeline()` I see the layout count is one, and this is where `m_descSetLayout` (what binds the camera uniform buffer) is used. What am I missing?

The related section of the tutorial is [here](https://nvpro-samples.github.io/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR/#camerasetup/raygeneration(raytrace.rgen)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See chapter 7.1:

```
  std::vector<vk::DescriptorSetLayout> rtDescSetLayouts = {m_rtDescSetLayout, m_descSetLayout};
  pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setSetLayoutCount(static_cast<uint32_t>(rtDescSetLayouts.size()));
  pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setPSetLayouts(rtDescSetLayouts.data());
```

The pipeline layout contains two descriptor set layouts, `m_rtDescSetLayout` for the acceleration structures at index 0 (set 0) and `m_descSetLayout` for the screne descriptors in index 1 (set 1). In Vulkan the set is automatically derived from a descriptor set layout's index in the pipeline layouts create info.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thanks for linking that together for me!