# Confused with some Vulkan concept

Tags: c++, vulkan

i have some few questions about Vulkan concepts.

**1. vkCmdBindDescriptorSets arguments**

```
// Provided by VK_VERSION_1_0
there is prototype:
void vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(
    VkCommandBuffer                             commandBuffer,
    VkPipelineBindPoint                         pipelineBindPoint,
    VkPipelineLayout                            layout,
    uint32_t                                    firstSet,
    uint32_t                                    descriptorSetCount,
    const VkDescriptorSet*                      pDescriptorSets,
    uint32_t                                    dynamicOffsetCount,
    const uint32_t*                             pDynamicOffsets);
```

i want to know the usage of descriptorSetCount and pDescriporSets, pipeline use only one VkDescriptorSet in a drawcall,but provide multiply same layout VkDescriptorSet means what?

**2. glsl uniform layout**

```
layout(set=0,binding =0) uniform UniformBufferObject
{
    mat4 view;
    mat4 projection;
    vec3 position_camera;
}ubo;
```

what does set means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Understanding Vulkan uniform layout's 'set' index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385747/understanding-vulkan-uniform-layouts-set-index)

vkCmdBindDescriptorSets update the current descriptorSet array.
the index of set define your shader use the one of array[index].